# New line on error message in KeyError - Python 3.3

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, python-idle

I am using Python 3.3 through the IDLE. While running a code that looks like:

```
raise KeyError('This is a \n Line break')
```

it outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise KeyError('This is a \n Line break')
KeyError: 'This is a \n Line break'
```

I would like it to output the message with the line break like this:

```
This is a
 Line Break
```

I have tried to convert it to a string before or using os.linesep but nothing seems to work. Is there any way I can force the message to be correctly shown on the IDLE?

---

If I raise an `Exception` (instead of `KeyError`) then the output is what I want, but I would like to still raise a `KeyError` if possible.

Comment: Please note I wrote "above", i.e. message is shown as "This is a \n Line break" and not as I expect "below" with the new line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You problem has nothing to do with IDLE.  The behavior you see is all from Python.  Running current repository CPython interactively, from a command line, we see the behavior you reported.

```
Python 3.7.0a2+ (heads/pr_3947:01eae2f721, Oct 22 2017, 14:06:43)
[MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

>>> raise KeyError('This is a \n Line break')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'This is a \n Line break'
>>> s = 'This is a \n Line break'

>>> s
'This is a \n Line break'
>>> print(s)
This is a
 Line break
>>> raise Exception('This is a \n Line break')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: This is a
 Line break
>>> raise IndexError(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: This is a
 Line break
>>> try:
...   raise  KeyError('This is a \n Line break')
... except KeyError as e:
...   print(e)

'This is a \n Line break'
>>> try:
...   raise  KeyError('This is a \n Line break')
... except KeyError as e:
...   print(e.args[0])

This is a
 Line break
```

I don't know why KeyError acts differently from even IndexError, but printing e.args[0] should work for all exceptions.

## EDIT

The reason for the difference is given in [this old tracker issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue2651), which quotes a comment in the `KeyError` source code:

> ```
> /* If args is a tuple of exactly one item, apply repr to args[0].
>        This is done so that e.g. the exception raised by {}[''] prints
>          KeyError: ''
>        rather than the confusing
>          KeyError
>        alone.  The downside is that if KeyError is raised with an
> explanatory
>        string, that string will be displayed in quotes.  Too bad.
>        If args is anything else, use the default BaseException__str__().
>     */
> ```

This section appears in the `KeyError_str` object definition in `Objects/exceptions.c` of the Python source code.

I will mention your issue as another manifestation of this difference.

Comment: It's interesting that it only happens for KeyError, not on ValueError or anything

Answer (score 5):

There *is* a way to get the behavior you want: Simply subclass `str` and override `__repr__`:

```py
    class KeyErrorMessage(str):
        def __repr__(self): return str(self)
    msg = KeyErrorMessage('Newline\nin\nkey\nerror')
    raise KeyError(msg)
```

Prints:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ...
> File "", line 5, in 
> raise KeyError(msg)
> KeyError: Newline
> in
> key
> error